# React navigation: Apply SafeAreaView globally with Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, iphone-x

I am trying to apply the `SafeAreaView` to my app in a globally way to avoid insert it into each view separately but when I do that, a shadow appears at the top and bottom of the views and I realized that was because I applied the `SafeAreaView` from my index.js but when I do directly in each view, it works as expected, do you know why or am I doing something wrong?

**With SafeAreaView in index.js**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: 'transparent',
  },
});

const AppContainer = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#EEEEEE" barStyle="dark-content" />
      <AppWithNavigationState />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </Provider>
);
```

[image]

**With SafeAreaView in the specific view**

[image]

I've trying to remove that shadow but is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `shadowColor: 'transparent'` to the `cardStyle` of the `stackNavigator` wherever you are using it in your `routeConfig`

Like this

```
cardStyle: {
    shadowColor: 'transparent'
  }
```